# Set max width of ErrorProvider's tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms

By default the tooltip used by `ErrorProvider` to show the error message will extend the full width of the screen. This makes it hard for the user to read the error message.

I know I can set the maximum width of a tooltip by sending the `TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH` message to the tooltip and thus make it wrap the contained text. How can I do the same for the tooltip of the `ErrorProvider`?

Note: I am not looking for a solution that requires altering the messages (e.g. adding newlines in the messages).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [You can't](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ErrorProvider.cs,65837b3d842a6763).  Writing brief but informative messages that fit a tooltip well is a skill.  Best left to a professional writer.

Comment: Would be nice if EnsureCreated was virtual, but it's not... About the message size, well that is something that sometimes you can't control (e.g. the message is returned from another system) or has to include certain information to be of any use to the user.